# Can I emulate mouseover in Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, cheerio

There is this website called [when2meet](https://when2meet.com) and when you set up an event, when you look at the group availability and hover over one of the blocks, the left side changes. I wanted to scrape info from the available menu in this pop-up.

I tried using JQuery and using .hover() but to no avail.

Comment: Cheerio just parses HTML and allows you to query its elements. It's not a browser emulator. It won't actually render the page and execute JavaScript on it.

Comment: @CherryDT So I can't do anything about it? Are there any other ways that can do this specific function?

Comment: Analyze the code/behavior of that function and find out where it loads its data from. Then read and interpret that same data source. Maybe it's from an AJAX request, maybe it's from data that was embedded in the page elsewhere, who knows, you need to trace it and find out and emulate the same behavior. (Or of course you can use a whole headless browser instead, like Puppeteer, but that may be cracking a nut with a sledgehammer, as it will be a lot slower and require more resources to run.)